# JAXB is unavailable After migrating to Java 17

Tags: spring-boot, jaxb, java-17

I migrated my application from Java 11 and spring boot 2 to Java 17 and spring boot 3, and I changed in Pom.xml my library

```
javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api
```

to

```
jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api
```

Everything seems to work fine, but at the start of my application I got this log:

```
WARN 3302 --- [           main] c.a.u.Base64                             : JAXB is unavailable. Will fallback to SDK implementation which may be less performant.If you are using Java 9+, you will need to include javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api as a dependency.
```

Is this something that I should wonder about? Can I remove this log without including on libraries?

Comment: Do you have an update on this?

Comment: I decided just to ignore it, because it's just a log and doesn't have any impact on the application